# How to access text button on individual TListViewItem

Tags: c++, firemonkey, c++builder-xe8

I have a Firemonkey [TListView](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.ListView.TListView) component which I have customized to include a `Text` and `TextButton` component on each item.  To customize my `TListView` component, I followed the "Using the Custom Value" section of [this documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Customizing_FireMonkey_ListView_Appearance).

I need to hide the `TextButton` on certain items within my list.  I have figured out how to hide all of the `TextButton` components in the list at once using:

`MyListView->ItemAppearanceObjects->ItemObjects->TextButton->Visible = false;`

However I cannot figure out how to access the `TextButton` of an individual row, in order to hide the specific buttons I need hidden.  How can I gain access to the `TextButton` of an individual row within my list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`TListViewItem.Objects`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.ListView.TListViewItem.Objects) property to access the various sub-objects of a list item, eg:

```
MyListView->Items->Item[index]->Objects->TextButton->Visible = false;
```